# extracting metadata of Excel files, incl. author, with R

Tags: r

I understand `file.info()` (in R) extracts data including file size, date of last modification, date of last access etc. of a chosen file. Unfortunately this information doesn't match what is available on right-clicking of an Excel 2016 file (in a Windows 10 environment) and going to Properties --> Details and doesn't include the author of the respective file.

Is there a function or method available in R to extract the information above (i.e. name of file, date of creation, date of last modification, author as per right-clicking of file in a Windows 10 environment), possibly to a data-frame?

I've been googling around for a while without success.

I asked my colleagues to collect (non-patient-identifiable) data in Excel files (one file per patient) and some of the data collectors struggle to link these files with other entries they completed on another system (which unexpectedly failed to provide a link to connect the two data-sets). I thought by providing information on collected data, as above, data-collectors might find it easier to identify their entries.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem recently and discovered that only properties that have been previously written will be available. For example: If creator tag is missing, that item will not appear in the XML data.

```
# Simulate a file with openxlsx
library(openxlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, 'SheetOne')
writeData(wb, 'SheetOne', mtcars)
addCreator(wb, 'From R with Love')     # add creator   
saveWorkbook(wb, 'test_file.xlsx', overwrite=TRUE)
 
# Use XML library and unzip function, to get metadata in docProps/core.xml
library(XML)
info <- xmlTreeParse(unzip('test_file.xlsx','docProps/core.xml'))

# Transform to a list and see available elements
info <- xmlToList(info)
names(info)
[1] "creator"        "lastModifiedBy" "created"       
 
# Get an item by name
info$creator
[1] "From R with Love"
```